# Сортировка массива объектов по совпадению полей объектов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов:

```
var mas = [
{
    from: 'Барселона',
    to: 'Мадрид'
},
{
    from: 'Москва',
    to: 'Барселона'
},
{
    from: 'Мадрид',
    to: 'Лондон'
}];
```

Как видно из примера внутри каждого объекта есть поля from и to. Нужно отсортировать этот массив так, что бы получилось вот так:

```
var mas = [
{
    from: 'Москва',
    to: 'Барселона'
},
{
    from: 'Барселона',
    to: 'Мадрид'
},
{
    from: 'Мадрид',
    to: 'Лондон'
}];
```

Естественно в реальности этих объектов больше. Желательно без использования других библиотек и фреймов. Саму сортировку я и сам могу сделать, но не могу понять по какому принципу выбирать первый и последний объектов.

Comment: Не совсем понятен принцип сортировки. Как, например, должен быть отсортирован такой массив: `[ { from: 'Москва', to: 'Лондон' }, { from: 'Москва', to: 'Петушки' }, { from: 'Иваново', to: 'Великий Устюг' } ]`? Формализуйте, пожалуйста, критерий сортировки.

Comment: В примере представлен массив объектов, а не массив массивов. Пожалуйста, называйте вещи своими именами. Я правильно понимаю, что to элемента массива N должен быть равен from элемента массива N+1? Если так, что делать с дубликатами, когда может быть несколько одинаковых from & to?

Comment: Правильно поняли. Прошу прощения за "массив массивов", недавно только познакомился с js

Comment: @fori1ton, таких совпадений from'ов нет.

Comment: @CoolEsh Дубликатов нет.

Comment: А совпадения `to` есть? А что делать с таким массивом: `[ { from: 'Москва', to: 'Лондон' }, { from: 'Лондон', to: 'Петушки' }, { from: 'Иваново', to: 'Великий Устюг' }, { from: 'Великий Устюг', to: 'Владивосток' } ]`? Ещё раз предлагаю вам сформулировать чёткие условия задачи. Правильно сформулированная задача - это половина решения.

Comment: Первое `from` равно последнему `to`? То есть циклический ли в итоге получается маршрут? Если да, то нужно спрашивать о тех, кто это придумал, какую они хотят видеть точку отправления. Если не циклический, то находите первое `from`, которое не равно ни одному `to`, а дальше уже сортировка по алгоритму.

Comment: @MasterAlex, тут упорядочивание, но не сортировка.

Comment: @Qwertiy, совершенно не хочу разделять в данном примере понятия упорядочивание и сортировка, потому что многие упорядочивания вполне вписываются в понятие сортировка, и многие сортировки вписываются в понятие упорядочивание. Тем более, что это совсем не суть :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, я имел в виду, что для алгоритма сортировки нужна транзитивная функция сравнения, а тут проще выполнить упорядочивание за линейное время без неё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то можно посмотреть, какой из городов встречается только один раз и находится в поле 'from' (в вашем примере – Москва). Поставить этот объект в массив первым. Дальше искать объект, у которого поле 'to' == полю 'from' предыдущего объекта. И поставить его следующим объектом. (в вашем примере

```
{
    from: 'Барселона',
    to: 'Мадрид'
}
```

И так далее.

Comment: Все правильно, но проблема в том, что я встал на реализации этого...

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм такой, под ES5 сам подгонишь:

```
function order(a) {
  "use strict";
  var temp = Object.create(null), c = Object.create(null), res = [];

  for (let x of a) {
    temp[x.from] = x;
    c[x.from] ^= 1;
    c[x.to] ^= 1;
  }

  for (var from of Object.keys(c)) {
    if (c[from] && temp[from]) {
      break;
    }
  }

  do {
    res.push(from = temp[from]);
    from = from.to;
  } while(temp[from]);

  return res;
}

order([
  { from: 'Барселона', to: 'Мадрид'    },
  { from: 'Москва',    to: 'Барселона' },
  { from: 'Мадрид',    to: 'Лондон'    }
]);
```